# How can I build the native aarch64 Emacs application for Android on a x86_64 system?

Tags: build, android

I'm struggling to build Emacs from the feature/android branch. I tried running the `./configure` script this way:

```
ANDROIDJAR=~/Android/platforms/android-33-ext4/android.jar
BUILDTOOLS=~/Android/build-tools/33.0.2
ANDROIDCC=~/ndk/25.2.9519653/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android31-clang

./configure --with-android=$ANDROIDJAR ANDROID_CC=$ANDROIDCC SDK_BUILD_TOOLS=$BUILDTOOLS
```

But I get the following error:

```
configure: WARNING: Unable to locate a usable pkg-config
configure: error: The following required libraries were not found:
     gnutls
Maybe some development libraries/packages are missing?
To build anyway, give:
     --with-gnutls=ifavailable
as options to configure.
configure: error: Failed to cross-configure Emacs for android.
```

I manually downloaded the GnuTLS devel package for AArch64 and extracted somewhere in my home folder, but I have no idea how to make it recognizable from the script. I already tried `--with-build-sysroot=...` or setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, but with no success.

Then I just gave up and set `--with-gnutls=ifavailable`. However, I naturally got another similar error:

```
checking for library containing tputs... no
configure: error: The required function 'tputs' was not found in any library.
The following libraries were tried (in order):
  libtinfo, libncurses, libterminfo, libcurses, libtermcap
Please try installing whichever of these libraries is most appropriate
for your system, together with its header files.
For example, a libncurses-dev(el) or similar package.
```

But I encounter the the same difficulties, since I've yet to find a systematic approach for dealing with libraries when cross-compiling.

I'm using Fedora 37.

Comment: You have to install _all_ of the Emacs dependencies in the appropriate place within your cross-compilation tool chain. It would probably also help to have `pkg-config` properly installed too.

Comment: This question could be on stackoverflow, superuser, android, or here, with reasonably equal chance of finding someone who can answer it. For instance, see https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19559/413 which also links to a FAQ for building emacs.